# Using "New-Object" cmdlet in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to run some Powershell cmdlet in a C# program I've been working on.

The cmdlet I've been trying to run is the following:

```
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (user, (ConvertTo-SecureString pass –ASPlainText –Force));
```

And what I did in my C# programm was the following:

```
string user = textBox1.Text;
            string pass = textBox2.Text;



            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddCommand("New-Object");
            ps.AddArgument("System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("+user+", (ConvertTo-SecureString "+pass+" –ASPlainText –Force))");
            var cred = ps.Invoke();
```

But when i do this I get prompted with the following error:

```
A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (user, (ConvertTo-SecureString pass –ASPlainText –Force)).
```

So my question is, how can I run this Powershell cmdlet from my C# program, and store the result in a variable inside the C# program?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how Powershell works or are you only interested in creating the credential? If it is the latter you should be able to simply new up the credential in C#.

Comment: @MartinBrown I want to create the credential. So i don't need to make the call of the New-Object cmdlet from Powershell to create this credential?

Comment: Thats lucky because I know how to do that (answer below). I'm as suck as you are as to why the powershell method doesn't work. Maybe some other bright spark knows.

Comment: Have you been able to get anything out of the Invoke() method? Every time I run it the program seems to get stuck, it does not matter which cmdlet I chose to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done without invoking powershell. Whether thats useful or not depends upon what you are up to.

```
var user = "username";
var pass = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in "password")
{
    pass.AppendChar(c);
}
var cred = new System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(user, pass);
```

Comment: It actually is super useful as it is one lest invocation I need to make to PowerShell :) (Although I've not been able to do any at all, but that's a whole other problem).  
Thank you man!

Answer (score 2):

[Martin Brown's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57613115/45375) is definitely the best solution in your case.

---

As for **what you tried**:

You didn't correctly translate your PowerShell command to a PowerShell SDK call.
Specifically, the way you add arguments is incorrect:

> `ps.AddArgument("System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("+user+", (ConvertTo-SecureString "+pass+" –ASPlainText –Force))");`

- **You must add arguments *one by one***, via `.AddArgument(<val>)`, or, preferably, as *named parameters* via `.AddParameter(<name>, <val>)`).
- **You cannot use *embedded PowerShell commands* as arguments**.

If we leave the issue of obtaining a `SecureString` instance aside and use just a dummy instance, this is what your statement would have to look like:

```
ps.AddCommand("New-Object")
  .AddParameter("TypeName", "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential")
  .AddParameter("ArgumentList", new object[] { user, new System.Security.SecureString() });
```

Note the use of parameter names and how parameter `-ArgumentList` must be passed as an *array*.

---

**If you do need to execute *PowerShell code* via the SDK**, use the `.AddScript()` method instead, but note that you can only pass a *single string* that contains the code to execute (note the use of an interpolated C# string, `$"..."` for embedding C# variable values):

```
ps.AddScript(
  $"New-Object PSCredential \"{user}\", (ConvertTo-SecureString \"{pass}\" –AsPlainText –Force)"
);
```

*Caveat*: Unlike a command added with `.AddCommand()`, an `.AddScript()`-added command *always* fails *silently* on execution with `.Invoke()` - no exception occurs; you'll have to inspect `ps.HadErrors` and `ps.Streams.Error` to check for errors. By contrast, `.AddCommand()` does throw an exception if the target command reports a (statement-)terminating error (though these are rare; an example is passing an invalid parameter name).